# Ckeditor / WYSIWYG copy from pdf and retain style/images?

Tags: html, pdf, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I searched a lot but couldn't get the answer.

I want to retain copied text from `pdf` to `WYSIWYG editor`(Ckeditor).
I can retain style while copied from Word files but it does not work the same way when copied from `PDF`.

Original `pdf` is like this(I can't post image as reputation is `< 10` , please refer links):

**PDF text**
[image]

It shows following output after copy paste:

**After copy paste in WYSIWYG editor**
[image]

Please suggest plugin or code snippet for PDF to RTF conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CKEditor can paste only data which it gets from the browsers. It means that if browsers do not provide more data then the plain text there is nothing CKEditor can do.

Since version 4.5 CKEditor provide facade to handle Clipboard API and get all data which are pasted directly in the `paste` event. Every browser provide different data and you can easily check them:

```
editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ) {
  var types = evt.data.dataTransfer.$.types;

  console.log( types );

  for ( var i = 0; i < types.length; i++ ) {
    console.log( evt.data.dataTransfer.getData( types[ i ] ) );
  }

  // Additionally you can get information about pasted files.
  console.log( evt.data.dataTransfer.getFilesCount() );
} );
```

Note that Internet Explorer does not provide `types` array and support only `Text` and `URL` types.

To learn more about Clipboard Integration see [this guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_clipboard). Especially "Handling Various Data Types with Clipboard API" chapter which describe how to integrate data converter with the paste event, so if the PDF data are available in any browser you can use them during pasting.

Comment: Are you sure using this , PDF data will be copied properly as it is with styling ?

Comment: No, most browsers do not give you proper PDF document. But `dataTransfer` is the proper (according to W3C) way of reading data from the clipboard. The problem is browsers limitation and the fact they do not give all data, but there is nothing you can do without hacks like uploading a PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a common case in your system then imho the best thing you can do is to allow users to upload the PDF file, run server side software to transform PDF into HTML and then automatically insert it into CKEditor.

I have no recommendations though on which application to use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PDF files work in a different way that other text documents, so even if you try to paste its contents into a native word processor you won't get the same formatting.

This will vary depending on your PDF reader, but it's usual that images aren't pasted, tables are converted to plain text lines, etc...

If that happens in a native program that has full access to the clipboard, you can't expect anything better in a javascript application that depends on the data that the browser provides, and even after that you have to be careful with CKEditor because by default it includes filters to remove any formatting that it doesn't recognize so even more information can be lost at this last point.

Comment: I think that I have explained that the problem lies out of CKEditor and it's due to the PDF itself, so the only solution would be to not try to copy from PDF files or find a Pdf reader that allows copying the content the way that you want, but that's outside the scope of StackOverflow.